# Kendo grid with Dynamic columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing kendo grid with dynamic column header . Dynamic column header is working but data is not representing in correct cell .

Code link: `https://jsfiddle.net/upa87s9L/`

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.Reports.InvoiceReportViewModel>()
        .Name("UnInvoicedGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.CustomerName).Width(200);
            foreach (var date in ((SelectList)ViewBag.Date).Items)
            {
                columns.Group(group => group
                .Title(date.ToString())
                .Columns(Report =>
                {
                    Report.Bound(c => c.DocumentCount).Width(200);
                    Report.Bound(c => c.DossierId).Width(200);
                    Report.Bound(c => c.InvoiceLCTotal).Width(200);
                }
                )
               );
            }
            columns.Group(group => group
                .Title("Total")
                .Columns(Report =>
                {
                    Report.Bound(c => c.Document)
                    .Width(200);
                    Report.Bound(c => c.DossierId).Width(200);
                })
               );
        })
```

All Column Data is showing in all column

Comment: Jsfiddle does not work with the mvc controls. Try [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) instead.

Comment: what is actually happening? What is the intended layout as you seem to have the same columns being repeated here. Although you are applying a "dynamic" grouping with the date you appear to be binding to the same properties in your model so each date will have the same data. If you can provide the viewmodel structure and an example of the intended layout that may help resolve your issue.

Comment: public class InvoiceReportViewModel
    {
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public long DossierId { get; set; }
        public long DossierInternalID { get; set; }
        public decimal? InvoiceLCTotal { get; set; }
        public long InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FortnightStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FortnightEndDate { get; set; }
        public string Document { get; set; }

Comment: public string Date
        {
            get
            {
                if (!FortnightEndDate.HasValue && !FortnightStartDate.HasValue)
                  return "";
                return FortnightStartDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " To " + FortnightEndDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            }
        }